# Exact string matches in python 3

Tags: python, regex

I have a list:

```
listy = ['{eth0 blah', '{eth1 blah blah', '{eth2 blah blah', '{eth2.1 blah blah', '{eth2.2 blah blah', '{wl0 blah blah', '{wl0.1 blah blah', '{wl1 blah blah', '{wl1.1 blah blah']
```

Trying to find a regular expression which can find the exact match for say `'eth2'`, I do not want the match to return `'eth2.1' and eth2.2` as true

this is the code which i have already

```
    listy = ['{eth0 blah', '{eth1 blah blah', '{eth2 blah blah', '{eth2.1 blah blah', '{eth2.2 blah blah', '{wl0 blah blah', '{wl0.1 blah blah', '{wl1 blah blah', '{wl1.1 blah blah

        for i in listy:
            if re.match(r'eth2\b',i):
            #{do something}             
            print('found')
        else:
            #{do something else}     
            print('not found')
```

This code unfortunately finds all strings that starts with `eth2`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` also matches a dot character, use a space instead of it:

```
for elem in listy:
    if re.search('eth2 ', elem):
        print('found')
    else:
        print('not found')
```

If you are searching for a simple substring like `eth2`, you don't need a regular expression, you can use `find` method:

```
for elem in listy:
    if elem.find('eth2 ') != -1:
        print('found')
    else:
        print('not found')
```

Comment: Thanks KAdot, actually i should have been more clear about what my actual intention was. Each element in the list listy has more than say 'eth1' but instead 'eth1 blah blah'. this was the reason for me to choose regular expressions. I will edit the main question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for this.

```
words=[word for word in listy if 'eth2' in word]
```